# Inconsistent notation in definitions of the multivariable chain rule

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-forms, chain-rule

Sometimes I see the multivariable chain rule defined solely in terms of partial derivatives $$
\frac{df}{dt} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial t}.
$$
And sometimes I see it defined using a mix of partial derivatives and total derivatives $$
\frac{df}{dt} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{dx}{dt} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{dt}.
$$
And sometimes I see it defined using a mix of partial derivatives and differentials, which I guess is equivalent to the 2nd definition $$
df = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}dx + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} dy.
$$
Needless to say, this is all quite confusing for someone moving beyond elementary calculus but not in a formal math program.

Can anyone enlighten me as to whether these different expressions mean the same thing or different things? Are authors being imprecise? What are good pedagogical references illustrating the meanings behind these different definitions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second notation is preferable if $x$ and $y$ (and therefore $f$, in the end) depend only on a single variable $t$, so that the derivatives $dx/dt$ and $dy/dt$ are just ordinary single-variable derivatives. (Not *total* derivatives, that's something slightly different.)

But an ordinary derivative $dx/dt$ can be written as a partial derivative $\partial x/\partial t$ without much risk of confusion, and if you do that, you get the first notation.

The first notation is also what you would use in case $x$ and $y$ depend on other variables besides $t$, except that then you must also write a *partial* derivative $\partial f/\partial t$ on the left-hand side.

Comment: Thanks @Hans. Question - what is the difference between the derivative and the total derivative? I thought they were the same. And do you have a good reference illustrating the differences and uses of these related derivative and differential concepts (including partials, though these seem the most straight-forward)? Or do I just need to do a lot of study in math plus applications to problems in physics before the differences become apparent?

Comment: @ted: Well, you could call $df/dt$ a total derivative in this context if you like, but I don't think anyone would use that phrase for $dx/dt$ and $dy/dt$. It's even more common in the context where you have $f(x,y,t)$ to begin with, and then let $x$ and $y$ depend on $t$, so that you have to be careful to distinguish between the partial derivative $\partial f/\partial t$ and the “total derivative $df/dt$”. But I'm not a huge fan of these notations myself; as a mathematician I like to use different letters for different functions.

Comment: And the phrase “total derivative” also has a completely different meaning, as explained in the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_derivative). As for references, any decent calculus book ought to explain this, but I don't know exactly what you are looking for. Once you understand the principles (which are not *that* complicated) you should be able to decipher all the various notations that people use.

Comment: Thanks, what are your favorite *decent* calculus books? :-)

Comment: @ted: I was taught long ago from a Swedish textbook which I doubt that you're interested in, and after that I haven't really felt the need to read any other calculus textbooks, so I can't recommend any particular one...

Comment: But if you want more advanced books (“analysis” rather than “calculus”) there are many great options. I like the two-volume *Mathematical Analysis* by Zorich, for example.

Comment: Thanks. I've done quite a bit of analysis at the undergrad level. But the texts I've read ("baby Rudin" and "Marsden and Hoffman") mostly focus on the single variable cases. And I am having trouble right now navigating the intersection with multi-dimensional extensions, especially with manipulating differentials and partials since it's not really talked about as its own subject.